# Sobolev inequality for product of three functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I know that for product of function, Sobolev's inequality tell us that, for any $s>\tfrac{1}{2}$ the following holds: $$
\Vert uv\Vert_{H^s(\mathbb{R})}\leq c\Vert u\Vert_{H^s(\mathbb{R})} \Vert v\Vert_{H^s(\mathbb{R})},
$$
where, of course, $u,v\in H^s(\mathbb{R})$. Now, while reading a book I have found something like the following (this is what I think they did, there is no explanation actually): Consider three functions $u,v,w\in H^{1/6}(\mathbb{R})$. Is it true that $$
\Vert uvw\Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} \leq c \Vert u\Vert_{H^{1/6}(\mathbb{R})}\Vert v\Vert_{H^{1/6}(\mathbb{R})}\Vert w\Vert_{H^{1/6}(\mathbb{R})}?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it's really the Sobolev embedding and generalized Hölder that are doing the work.  The former shows that since
$$
\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{1} \left(\frac{1}{6} \right)
$$
we have the continuous embedding $H^{1/6}(\mathbb{R}) \hookrightarrow L^3(\mathbb{R})$.  Then, since
$$
1= \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{3}
$$
the general Hölder inequality says that
$$
\Vert f g h \Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} \le \Vert f   \Vert_{L^3(\mathbb{R})} \Vert g   \Vert_{L^3(\mathbb{R})} \Vert h   \Vert_{L^3(\mathbb{R})}. 
$$
Chaining these two bounds together then shows that
$$
\Vert f g h \Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} \le c \Vert f \Vert_{H^{1/6}(\mathbb{R})} \Vert g   \Vert_{H^{1/6}(\mathbb{R})} \Vert h   \Vert_{H^{1/6}(\mathbb{R})}
$$